# Error: Deployment failed Resource is not in the state deploymentSuccessful Finishing: CodeDeployDeployApplication

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, aws-code-deploy

I am quite new to azure devops. I am trying to deploy my app from azure to aws ec2 using codedeploy. The build pipeline is giving "Error: Deployment failed Dev-TitasEcom-Frontend Resource is not in the state deploymentSuccessful" error. I have searched a lot but could not find any proper resource to resolve the issue. Below given the code of azure-pipelines.yaml

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - dev
  paths:
    include:
      - ./*

jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      demands:
      - npm
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: false
#    - powershell: 'npm cache clean  --force'
#      displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
#      env:
#        APPDATA: npm-cache

#    - task: CodeDeployDeployApplication@1
#      inputs:
#        awsCredentials: 'AWS Service Con'
#        regionName: 'us-east-1'
#        applicationName: 'Dev-TitasEcom-Frontend'
#        deploymentGroupName: 'Dev-erp-Frontend'
#        #deploymentRevisionSource: 'workspace'
        #revisionBundle: 'Dev-erp-Frontend-Rev'
#        bucketName: 'Dev-erp-Frontend'
#        fileExistsBehavior: 'OVERWRITE'
#        batch: "true"
    
    - task: CodeDeployDeployApplication@1
      inputs:
        awsCredentials: 'AWS Service Con 1'
        regionName: 'us-east-1'
        applicationName: 'Dev-TitasEcom-Frontend-11'
        deploymentGroupName: 'Dev-erp-Frontend'
        environmentName: 'DevTitasecomFrontend-env-12'
        applicationType: 'version'
        bucketName: 'elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-3067722226831765'
        fileExistsBehavior: 'OVERWRITE'
        #versionLabel: 'v.0.01'
        batch: "true"

    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Npm Install'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "ci"
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Lint Client App'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "custom"
        customCommand: "run lint"
      continueOnError: true
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Copy Assets'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "custom"
        customCommand: "run copy-files"
      continueOnError: false
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'Build Client App'
      inputs:
        workingDir: "./"
        command: "custom"
        customCommand: "run build:prod"

# Archive files
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)' 
        includeRootFolder: true 
        archiveType: 'zip' # Options: zip, 7z, tar, wim
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/www.zip' 
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        Contents: 'www/**'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'titas-ecom-erp'
```

Comment: Can you go back to basics? Can you deploy your application manually using CodeDeploy, without any azure pipelines or other CICD tools?

Comment: sure. i will do it

Comment: Would you mind share the build log in your question? Have you checked whether the failure is caused by task timeout, try to extend the timeout time.https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/issues/87. BTW, make sure the Application Name is the name of the AWS CodeDeploy application.